# TypeError: firebase.default.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm using firebase for my web project.
especially, on server-side. I'd followed the official doc.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#node.js-apps
and It had said,

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and
// must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase services that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

and

```
// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

But it doesn't work. So I just try randoms with searching about this.

And Only it worked.

```
import firebase from "@firebase/app"

import "@firebase/auth"
import "@firebase/firestore"

...

firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

My Environment is this.

```
➜  firestore-test node --version
v14.7.0
➜  firestore-test firebase --version
8.6.0
➜  firestore-test npm --version
6.14.7
```

Why the official introduction doesn't work?
I'm assuming about the docs is old, and it occurred from Node 14+ version.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same frustration, but according to the release notes here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js in Version 8.0.0 - October 26, 2020

> Breaking change: browser fields in package.json files now point to ESM bundles instead of CJS bundles. Users who are using ESM imports must now use the default import instead of a namespace import.
>
> Before 8.0.0
>
> ```py
> import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
> ```
>
> After 8.0.0
>
> ```py
> import firebase from 'firebase/app'
> ```
>
> Code that uses require('firebase/app') or require('firebase') will still work, but in order to get proper typings (for code completion, for example) users should change these require calls to require('firebase/app').default or require('firebase').default. This is because the SDK now uses typings for the ESM bundle, and the different bundles share one typings file.